# How to find dynamically loaded modules (the static ones) programatically in windows

Tags: c++, c, windows

I'm trying to port the unix utility ldd to windows, because dependency walker and cygcheck don't quite give me the usage I'm looking for.  (also for the learning experience)

Ive been looking all over MSDN, for a windows API that lists dll dependencies of an executable, or even the storage format in the complied exe (just to filter it out), but I've been unable to find anything.

If anyone knows what API call windows uses for listing modules to load, or what patterns I can search for in an executable to find modules to load, please help me out
:)
thanks!

-note:  I'm not looking to profile for dynamic modules, just list the ones that are required at runtime

Comment: There is no API call for that.  Not a documented one anyway. You have to read the PE32 file format.

Comment: @Hans Passant: It's even worse than that -- if he's talking about runtime dynamic linking he needs to find all the calls to GetProcAddress and friends too.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: dynamic linking is 'modules that are required at runtime', LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress & fiends is dynamic loading.
It's a lot easier to get the list of the loaded modules at runtime (on Windows using Process Status API for instance) implicitly (the dynamically linked ones - loaded by the OS) or explicitelly (dynamic loaded ones - by the process itself).

Comment: @Eugen Dinca: The word *runtime* in my comment above is not insignificant. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686944(VS.85).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685090(VS.85).aspx

Comment: @Billy ONeal: I always thought dynamic linking = dll/so (as opposed to static linking = lib/a) and loading a library at runtime = dynamic loading (especially since the function names are LoadLibrary/dlopen)...
Anyway, I definitely see your point now (but I still think it's easier to get the list of modules loaded by a running process :) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modules loaded with loadlibrary api cannot be found in the exe imports table. So to trace those module we have to use one of the several api monitoring tools.
http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor

[www.apimonitor.com](http://www.apimonitor.com)

If that is not the case you can simply get all the imports from

> dumpbin /import abc.exe

(i am not exactly sure about the command line syntax)

dumpbin is a tool from windows sdk (visual studio also contains it)

Answer (score 1):

Personally, before I spent a lot of time trying to figure out the (likely complex) API calls for this,  I would consider running Dependency Walker in console mode and seeing if I could just extract the text data I needed from there.

Answer (score 1):

Useful links:

[PE COFF Spec](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/system/platform/firmware/PECOFF.mspx)

[X86 Disassembly/Windows Executable Files](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Windows_Executable_Files)

[MSDN Magazine Article Part 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301805.aspx)

[MSDN Magazine Article Part 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301808.aspx)

Area of your interest is generally imports directory. This two also may be useful:

[Tool Help Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686837.aspx)

[Debug Help Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679309.aspx)